# using solr in coldfusion - understanding

Tags: solr, coldfusion

This might be a very silly question, but please bear with me and help me out.

I have a basic understanding about what is solr? We have a solr search capability on our website built in coldfusion. I have never worked with searching on websites before. I did look up but I'm not quite clear.

Does it do a web search for the inputted string? 
Or does it to a database search of the string?

Thanks

Comment: In regard to use with ColdFusion [read this couple of pages](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/Developing/WS2B335964-A0DA-4add-B9FE-4041464EC9E1.html) and see if that helps.

Comment: The question is too broad to give anything specific, but do read up [Solr wiki](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/) if you need further details, and post back with specific questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solr is a search engine, which aggregates data and stores them in an indexed manner, and provides fast lookup. It uses Apache Lucene for indexing.

You could query Solr for a string, and it will return a list of matches, which can then be displayed in your website.

Refer to this presentation for an [introduction to Solr](http://www.slideshare.net/tomhill/an-introduction-to-solr).

Note that Solr gives a lot of features to enhance your user experience, i.e Faceted Navigation etc.

Comment: Thanks for the direction! all